# How to Overlap buttons/Text over an image with JavaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble placing buttons/text over an image I am using with JavaFX 8.

I used an ImageViewer to place the image but I am unable to actually get the rest ON TOP of the image.

I am using setTranslateX,Y to move the button around but it never overlaps.

Please tell me how I can solve this issue.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class Main extends Application{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }


    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        int x = 450;
        int y = 450;

        Image image = new Image("space.jpg",x,y, false, false);
        ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
        iv1.setImage(image);
        iv1.setPreserveRatio(true);
        iv1.setFitHeight(x);
        iv1.setFitWidth(y);


        Text text = new Text("hello");
        text.setFont(Font.font ("Arial", 27));

        Button button = new Button("Hello");
        button.setTranslateX(10);
        button.setTranslateY(10);
        button.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TOP);


        HBox root = new HBox();


        root.getChildren().add(iv1);
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        root.getChildren().add(button);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root,x,y);

        stage.setTitle("Space Blaster (New Game)");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? You want the button and text on top of the image, but where is the button supposed to be in relationship to the text?

Comment: Hi, I am not interested with the relationship between the button and the text. I am just having trouble overlapping the text/button over the image. In simple terms, my goal is to have the image act as the background picture and have the buttons / whatever on top.

Comment: Well it's quite hard to give an example if you don't explain how you want it to look, but I will try...

Comment: I just need to figure out how to overlap something over an image. My problem is wherever I move the button/text, it shows beside the image, instead of on top.

Comment: Here is an image as to what I am experiencing: http://puu.sh/erg77/7512937a40.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `StackPane` to overlay two nodes. For example:

```
Button button = new Button("Hello");
Text text = new Text("hello");

HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(button, text); // button will be left of text

Image image = new Image("space.jpg",x,y, false, false);
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();

StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
stackPane.getChildren().addAll(iv1, hbox); // hbox with button and text on top of image view

HBox root = new HBox();
root.getChildren().add(stackPane);

// etc
```

Another approach is just to put the controls (button and text) in a pane of some kind (e.g. `HBox`), and then to [use CSS to set a background image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) on the pane.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I will go look into stackpanes a bit more now.